# C# Concurrency and Agents

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Is there anything in C# similar to the new Microsoft C++11 Concurrency library that allows to build asynchronous agents (for example as it is done [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504791#createAgentClass)) ?

Comment: Isn't an asynchronous agent much like a .NET 4 Task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the new (beta) `async` keyword.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360